# How is ResNet different from FPN?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, faster-rcnn

I'm learning more about different variations of deep CNNs. Based from my understanding, ResNet makes use of skip connections that's also somehow shaped like a pyramid or triangle? How is this different to Feature Pyramid Network then?

Answer (score 0):

Typically people use FPNs for segmentation/detection tasks (dense pixel-wise predictions), with skip connection between different **levels**^1 of the network, while ResNet is used for classification/regression tasks (sparse, image-wise predictions), with skip connections within a residual block (between different **layers** of the network).

Another difference is, typically, in FPN you do perform some kind of upsample of feature maps (in a form of deconvolution or a interpolation followed by convolution), while ResNet consist of sequence of downsampling transformations (convolutions and poolings).

[image]

Schematically, FPNs could consist of ResNet (which transform spatial width x height into features), followed by a "reversed ResNet" (which transforms features into spatial width x height), with skip-connections between corresponding spatial levels, forming a pyramid, hence the name.